# Korean Tile Roof Approach

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I'm looking to model an accurate Korean traditional tile roof for archival purposes. I'm quite new to Blender so I'm still unsure of many things. I am wondering how to best approach this problem.

Here are some images of the kind of roof I'm trying to model:

[image: A smaller manner of roof with very little curve to it]
A smaller manner of roof with very little curve to it
[image: The corner of a larger hip/gable manner of roof with a normal amount of curve to it. Notice the differing overlap along the bottom edge of the tiling.]
The corner of a larger hip/gable manner of roof with a normal amount of curve to it. Notice the differing overlap along the bottom edge of the tiling.
[image: A wider full view of the hip/gable style of roof]
A wider full view of the hip/gable style of roof

What I have so far is this (modelled in Rhino3D and imported into Blender):

[image: This is the main roof structure to be tiled, it is of the hip/gable type and will have a number of curves and joining moments.]
This is the main roof structure to be tiled, it is of the hip/gable type and will have a number of curves and joining moments.
[image: This is a little brick shed being archived, it will have the more simple style of roof shown in the very first reference photo. Also seen is my early attempts and beginning to tile it by hand using array modifiers and so forth.]
This is a little brick shed being archived, it will have the more simple style of roof shown in the very first reference photo. Also seen is my early attempts and beginning to tile it by hand using array modifiers and so forth.
[image: These are the three types of tiles used in these roofs, the whole thing can be constructed out of these three.]
These are the three types of tiles used in these roofs, the whole thing can be constructed out of these three.

The important things are the *double tile* at the roof's edge—how the tiles break even spacing at the bottom edge of the roof by having one more overlapped tile—and the curve of the roof. As well, I think it would be nice to have some sort of procedural offset to the tiles to mimick a sort of *hand layed* æsthetic, and, if possible, a modifier to slightly skew the shapes of the tiles to make them look more handmade like in this photo:

[image: This photo shows some older roofs that are hand tiled with handmade tiles and shows the kind of effect I'm looking for.]
This photo shows some older roofs that are hand tiled with handmade tiles and shows the kind of effect I'm looking for.

I did a little study using geometry nodes and following a Youtube tutorial and made this:

[image: Roof study I made using geometry nodes.]

But I am not sure if its possible, and do not know how anyway, to apply it to this problem. Ultimately I'd like to do something like this using these premade geometries I have shown in the above photo (the three premade rooftiles) and, using those, apply modifiers to array them, skew them, deform them, and so forth. I feel like the approach for this could be quite straightforward, but, I do not know enough to know what it would be. Any and all help is very much appreciated!